# Magento 2 setup hangs on 89%

Tags: magento2, setup, error-log, php-7

Magento 2 installation page (step 6) freezes on 89% where in console log it stops on:

*Module 'Magento_ConfigurableSampleData':
Installing data..*

in my **/etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini** file I have the follwing:

```
max_execution_time = 18000
max_input_time = 18000
memory_limit = 2G
```

**What is wrong? why it does not continue after reaching 89% even if I wait for 1 hour?! how can I fix it?**

note that the following is my php version:

```
PHP 7.0.5-3+donate.sury.org~wily+1 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
```

and the following is my Apache2 version:

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.12 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Jul 24 2015 15:59:00
```

in /var/log/apache2/error.log I have the following at the time of the setup:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php on line 63, referer: http://[IP address]/setup/
```

Comment: Anything in the Magento or server error logs?

Comment: the following is what I found in the error log: "PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php on line 63, referer: http://[IP address]/setup/"

Comment: the Magento 2 setup which you run , is with sample data or without sample data ?

Comment: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/11124 read this, maybe it helps

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase `max_execution_time` in `php.ini` to 18000 (30 minutes). And then restart your Apache Web server.

From official Magento dev doc:

> we recommend you increase the value in `php.ini` to 18000 (30
>   minutes). You can use a larger or smaller value if it helps.

We can read more here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/trouble/php/tshoot_70pct.html

**Update:**  Following the @Steve Johnson comment, we currently have a problem with 7.0.5 version, please use 7.0.4 version.

> There is a known PHP issue that affects our code
>   compiler when using PHP 7.0.5. We recommend you *not* use
>   PHP 7.0.5.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/system-requirements.html

**[EDIT]**

Install the Magento software using the command line. It works out of the box.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-subcommands.html

For example command:

```
magento setup:install --base-url=http://127.0.0.1/magento2/ \
--db-host=localhost --db-name=magento --db-user=magento --db-password=magento \
--admin-firstname=Magento --admin-lastname=User --admin-email=user@example.com \
--admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin123 --language=en_US \
--currency=USD --timezone=America/Chicago --use-rewrites=1
```

Comment: I tried, thus changed in the question as while... but same, hangs on 89% ... however I had a look on the error.log file and I found: "PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php on line 63, referer: http://[IP address]/setup/" at the time of setup

Comment: You tried to restart your Apache after increasing max execution time?

Comment: Yes of course I did

Comment: Try to increase `memory_limit` to 4G. The same issue here: https://community.magento.com/t5/Installing-Magento-2/Magento2-installation-stuck-while-installing-sample-data/td-p/13682

Comment: There is a known issue with PHP 7.0.5. I'm not sure it affects you or not but check the [System Requirements](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/system-requirements.html) page. You might need to drop back to 7.0.4.

Answer (score 0):

Try following

- Create phpinfo() file and check max_execution_time is 18000
- Restart your Apache and try again

Answer (score 0):

Magento does not log the actual errors.
Try increasing the value for max_allowed_packet of your mysql server.

> To increase the value, open /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf in a text editor and locate the value for max_allowed_packet. Save your changes to mysql.cnf, close the text editor, and restart MySQL (service mysql restart).
>
> To optionally verify the value you set, enter the following command at a mysql> prompt:
>
> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet';

Answer (score 0):

Try MySQL commands :

> SET GLOBAL wait_timeout = 7200;
>   SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet = 1000000000;
>   SET GLOBAL net_buffer_length = 1000000;

I also had leke the same problems with M2 (sample data version) installation but on 67% point.

Clean M2 haven't this problems.